# Is it possible to give a function as an enum constructor param?

Tags: java, java-8, enums

I'm using a few components that I cannot edit, my situation is like this

```
private enum Radio {

    SPACE(" "),
    PLUS("+"),
    MINUS("-");


    private String value;

    private Radio(final String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static void setSelection(final CodeEntry entry, final String flag) {
        entry.getButtonWhite().setSelection(flag.equals(SPACE.value));
        entry.getButtonGreen().setSelection(flag.equals(PLUS.value));
        entry.getButtonRed().setSelection(flag.equals(MINUS.value));
    }
}
```

I don't like this. I want to associate the button with the enum. Anything else is sub-par to say the least. But I don't know how

```
private enum Radio {

    SPACE(" ", CodeEntry::getButtonWhite),
    PLUS("+", CodeEntry::getButtonGreen),
    MINUS("-", CodeEntry::getButtonRed);
...
```

`static reference to the non-static method getButtonWhite()`

What I want is a sort of `accept(T t)` thing. So I give a getter as a constructor parameter, then I call that getter on an object with `enum.accept(t)`, like so:

```
private enum Radio {

    SPACE(" ", CodeEntry::getButtonWhite),
    PLUS("+", CodeEntry::getButtonGreen),
    MINUS("-", CodeEntry::getButtonRed);

    setSelection(final CodeEntry entry, final String flag) {
        // Button button = Radio.valueOf(flag).accept(entry);
        // button.setSelection(true);
        Radio.valueOf(flag).accept(entry).setSelection(true);
    }
```

I'm not sure if this is possible, and the syntax is kinda defeating me.

### Limitations of my example

While I appreciate any workable answer, the following things I cannot change so I'll only accept an answer that ticks the following:

- The flag is string and will be a string no matter what.
- The entries will have getButtonX, that will not change.
- I am using java 8, that will not change.
- I want to associate the getter with the enum, it must be a constructor param.

Comment: what is the implementation of `CodeEntry` in the question? and a sample of how `getButtonX` signature looks like?

Comment: Make the enum abstract and let the individual enum values implement `getButton`?

Comment: @Naman CodeEntry  has 3 button getters, nothing else that is relevant here. The buttons are radio buttons that I only want to select the correct one, based on the string flag.

Comment: @MCMastery The syntax is killing me. I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: @Kalec I'll post an answer

Comment: You didn't mention, hence, can you make `getButtonX` static? @Kalec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you haven't specified the type(s) that the `CodeEntry::getButton*` methods return, I'm going to denote it `T` for my example.

---

Your second `enum` parameter can be a `Function<CodeEntry, T>`, which will allow you to use a method reference:

```
private enum Radio {
    SPACE(" ", CodeEntry::getButtonWhite),
    PLUS("+", CodeEntry::getButtonGreen),
    MINUS("-", CodeEntry::getButtonRed);

    private final String value;

    private final Function<CodeEntry, T> buttonFunction;

    private Radio(final String value, Function<CodeEntry, T> buttonFunction) {
        this.value = value;
        this.buttonFunction = buttonFunction;
    }

    public static void setSelection(final CodeEntry entry, final String flag) {
        Arrays.stream(values())
              .filter(radio -> flag.equals(radio.value))
              .findAny()
              .ifPresent(radio -> {
                 radio.buttonFunction.apply(entry).setSelection(true);
              });
    }
}
```

This assumes that the `flag` parameter will be either `" "`, `"+"`, or `"-"`.

Comment: The `valueOf` wouldn't return the `Function` to `apply`, you can rather use `Radio.valueOf(flag).buttonFunction.apply(entry).setSelection(true)`. Even then if the flag is supposed to be any of the strings like `+` or `-`, this wouldn't work.

Comment: Yep this is the solution. A part of the syntax is still defeating me if you wouldn't mind clearing it up. So I have a Function<TypeThatHasGetter, GetterResultType>. Then the param for the enums is TypeThatHasGetter::getMethod // returns GetterResultType. Is that how it understands things? It has to be "TypeThatHasGetter" :: "someMethod that returns GetterResultType", right? I hope you understand, I'm not explaining well at all.

Comment: @Kalec That’s correct. `Function` takes two generic types; the first being the input, and the second being the output. The function itself is responsible for mapping the input to the output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using an `abstract` method:

```
private enum Radio {
    SPACE(" ") {
        @Override
        public void setSelection(final CodeEntry entry, final String flag) {
            // do whatever
        }
    },
    ...

    public abstract void setSelection(final CodeEntry entry, final String flag);
```

Honestly I had a little trouble understanding exactly what you wanted, but hopefully that helps?

Comment: `enum` is `abstract` by default, so there's no need to create an `interface` to define an `abstract` method. I'd also argue that this will result in code that's less readable than what the OP currently has.

Comment: @JacobG. lol. I knew that, idk why I forgot that, thanks. Yeah this may not be the best approach, but it is one possible solution